# rescue RecordNotFound in Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, inherited-resources

How can I rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Activeadmin for all my resources?

I know in Rails I can put `rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)` in the ApplicationController, is there an equivalent way of doing this in ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register FooBar do
  controller do
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :show_errors
    def show_errors
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:
You can do this at one place for all resources:

```
require 'active_admin/base_controller'
ActiveAdmin::BaseController.class_eval do
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :show_errors
  def show_errors
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: is there a way to configure that in one place for all my resources instead of duplicating that code in every resource file??

Comment: This didn't work for me.  No matter what I do my rescue block doesn't catch errors I raise.  Also PS:  what variables does does show_errors have access to?